# Features repeated on select in a no-wrapped vector layer ol3

Tags: openlayers

I have a map created with gdal2tiles on OL3. I added a Vector layer, and some features, but when I select a feature, this is repeated horizontally, even when the vector layer is non-wrapped.

Some screenshots

[image: none]

[image: hover]